# What do you call it when you can't smell something?

Tags: single-word-requests, sense-verbs

The man who cannot see is *blind*.

The man who cannot hear is *deaf*.

The man who cannot talk is *mute*.

What is the man who cannot smell?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anosmia

Comment: The one chosen to clean the garbage can.

Comment: If this is an ELL question - note that very few people / basically nobody would know the word anosmia.  What you would say is **lost your sense of smell**. That's the standard phrase.

Comment: I googled "cannot smell" and first result gives the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A person who cannot smell suffers from **anosmia.**

Comment: And is thus *anosmic*. (Beat me by 30 seconds).

Comment: @TimLymington ...................Bless Google........

Comment: An _anosmic_ suffers from a deficiency of osmium.

Comment: As you will note from my deleted post below, my gamble went badly wrong. But 'olfactive' would certainly appear to be the antonym of 'anosmic'.

Comment: @JohnLawler You have just brought me a little sunshine!

Comment: +1 And then there's [*smell blind* ...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walk_Hard:_The_Dewey_Cox_Story)

Comment: @JohnLawler: Damn! I was thinking it was [**omnium**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Third_Policeman).

Answer (score 1):

There are about 5% of people who have no smell or diminished smell. Anosmia is for those of us who have absolutely no ability to smell, WHICH MEANS "taste" is mostly gone. 95% of what most call "taste" is flavor, which is linked to a working olfactory nerve.

Answer (score 0):

Anosmatic works too.
                                                .
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anosmatic?s=t